# Javafx linking between Class and Combobox

Tags: javafx, combobox

I have a javafx class `ShowBytes` which contains bytes a-z . Each byte is defined as follows

```
public static final byte A = (byte) 0x00;
```

I want to populate the list of bytes in the class and display them in a combobox. Is there any way I can link the the combobox items to the bytes in the class `ShowBytes` so that if I choose `A` in the combobox it still represents byte 0.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show the variable names in the `ComboBox`, but keep make the item type `Byte`? Are those values even unique? Why do you want to do this? What is the benefit of using `Byte` as item type instead of simply converting the item to `byte` when it's used?

Comment: The bytes are going to be sent to a device through serial communication to a development board. The bytes will be interpreted by the device as a command. Is it possible to have a function called getbytes(String Bytename) which will return the byte from the class.

Comment: Can't you modify that class and put the data in a more suitable data structure?

Comment: Yeah I could. The problem is i`m a newbie to javafx so i`m still trying to get my head around somethings. What type of data structures would suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class containing the byte and a `String` and override the `toString` method to return the string. You can get the value from that class, if it's needed

e.g.

```
ObservableList<NamedByteValue> bytes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

// just filling it with some sample values here
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    bytes.add(new NamedByteValue((byte) (c - 'A'), Character.toString(c)));
}

ComboBox<NamedByteValue> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(bytes);
comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue.getValue()));
```

```
public static class NamedByteValue {

    private final byte value;
    private final String name;

    public NamedByteValue(byte value, String name) {
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public byte getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```